# explaination of object javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I am looking at javascript file and they started it off as

```
var myPage = new Object();
var myDocument = document.all;
```

then there is some code. and then this part

```
myPage.Search = myDocument.Search;
myPage.Search.searchType = "Description";
```

I am using eclipse with aptana. I want to know why would someone wanna do this

```
myPage.Search = myDocument.Search;
```

why not

```
myDocument.Search.searchType = "Description";
```

Comment: A possible duplicate from the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883894/whats-this-javascript-function-doing

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other two questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883924/javascript-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883894/whats-this-javascript-function-doing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the code. if myPage is passed into a function later, the `myPage.Search = myDocument.Search;` will allow the client function to access `Search` without having to access `myDocument`. The assignment to `searchType` can then be done either way.

The fact that they are using `document.all` is a good indication that you want to stay far away from that code. `document.all` hasn't been a sensible way to access elements since IE 4. at least use `document.getElementById()` -- But really, use a library like jQuery or Prototype.