# Explaining the setState function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what this function is doing

```
var page = new Object();  
page.testSearch.btnSearch.setState = function() {
    this.disable(!(page.testSearch.searchString.value.trim().length > 1));  
}
```

Comment: Do you use any JavaScript library like Prototype.js or jQuery? It might be impossible to tell what your code does without looking at more code with some HTML.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883894/whats-this-javascript-function-doing

Comment: If that code is verbatim it seems extremely unlikely(\*) to work. You can't assign something to `page.testSearch.someProperty` if you haven't put a `testSearch` property on `page`. (\*: it's possible if there were some prototyping going on on Object, but that would be unlikely and highly inadvisable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates a new empty JavaScript object called page. Then it adds a property to the object (which in this case turns out to be a function). It looks like it is relying on another function which you haven't pasted in called disable (but I think that we can assume that it disables something in some way!) which will disable something if the text in `page.testSearch.searchString` is shorter than 1 character long.

It looks to me like it works on a form on a web page.

It must be said that this style of JavaScript coding is a little out-dated, and some might argue that this piece of code would be better written as using *object literal notation*.

Comment: how would you rewrite with object literal..Thanks